# PHP enable 2 links in same page after submit button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP form with Name, Email & Submit Button.
Below Submit, there are two disabled links in grey.
1. PDF download, 
2. redirect to other site.

Once Submit button is hit, form data sent to mail and below two links activate.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="contactform" role="form" action = "popupform.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="NAMN:">  
    </div>
  </div> 
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="name" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="E-POST:">   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="Ja">Ja
  </div> 
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SUBMIT</button>
    </div></div>
</form>
```

Used popup on submit

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;font-size:25px;">Ladda ner bästa tipsen</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:right;"><a href="allfiledownload.php">Download All As Zip</a></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">
    <p><a href="download.php?filename=#"  class="btn btn-default" type="button"  style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/pdf-512.png" width="30px"><br><span style="color:#000;">LADDA NER</span></a></p>
    <p><a href="download.php?filename=#"  class="btn btn-default" type="button"  style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/pdf-512.png" width="30px"><br><span style="color:#000;">LADDA NER</span></a></p>
    <p><a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" type="button"  style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/tips1.jpg" width="30px"><br><span style="color:#b21887;">Tio tips för att<br> bli en <br>miljonkonsult</span></a></p>

    </div></div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

But i need two icons or links to be shown below the submit button.

Comment: What did you tried ? You'll have to share your code in order for we can help you.

Comment: Where is your code? Aside from the HTML part.

Comment: Where is your PHP code? What you've posted wouldn't help very likely.

Comment: where is your form?